# Concatenate json array objects with jq

Tags: json, bash, jq, aws-cli

I have below json file :

```
{
"EventId": "60a0490c",
"Resources": [
    {
        "ResourceType": "AWS::STS::AssumedRole", 
        "ResourceName": "AutoScaling"
    }, 
    {
        "ResourceType": "AWS::IAM::Role", 
        "ResourceName": "arn:aws:iam:autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling"
    }
    ]
}
```

I want to concatenate the key-value pairs from Resources element, and output on single line as:

```
60a0490c,AutoScaling=AWS::STS::AssumedRole#AWS::IAM::Role=arn:aws:iam:autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling
```

I tried it as :

```
cat file.json | jq '.EventId + "," + (.Resources[] | join("="))' -r
```

It gives me output as :

```
60a0490c,AutoScaling=AWS::STS::AssumedRole
60a0490c,AutoScaling=AWS::IAM::Role=arn:aws:iam:autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling
```

It creates new entry for each key-value pair, I want it to be on single line with different delimeter (#)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the command that you use give the output shown by you? On my mac output is different: 

`60a0490c,AWS::STS::AssumedRole=AutoScaling

60a0490c,AWS::IAM::Role=arn:aws:iam:autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling`

Comment: Hi Ashutosh, I tried my above command on both ubuntu and mac, same output. $ jq --version
jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this:

```
jq ' .EventId + "," + ([(.Resources[] | join("="))] | join("#"))' -r file
60a0490c,AWS::STS::AssumedRole=AutoScaling#AWS::IAM::Role=arn:aws:iam:autoscaling.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling
```

To use the second `join()`, just enclose the result in an array `[...]`.

Note that the first key/value is not swapped as shown in your example (i.e. `Autoscaling` is the value and not the key).

Comment: Yes, this solved my problem, Thanks oliv for quick response.